# Getting introspection metadata from inside a container

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

I'm wondering how to access [introspection metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-introspection.html) from inside a container running in an **ECS cluster**.

The documentation recommends to call:

```
curl http://localhost:51678/v1/metadata
```

Which works on the **EC2 instance** itself, but not from the container, which is not on the same network (in *bridge* network mode).

However, the command to access [EC2 introspection metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) works well because the call has to be done to an IP address, which is reachable from the container:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

---

I guess one way to do would be to change the network mode to share the host interface, but in the current setup that's something I'd prefer to avoid.

In context, I'm trying to move my code that sends custom *Cloudwatch metrics* out from a local script to a utility container. I would like to avoid specifying stuff such as the *ECS cluster name*, when it could be retrieved from an API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a way.

The container running on the **EC2 instance** from the **ECS cluster** can access the host IP, either from its private IP (which is not reliable), or from the **Docker Bridge IP**, and the introspection calls can be run on them.

The **Docker Bridge IP** option, which defines on which network the containers will run, defaults to *172.17.0.0/16*, and can be modified in the file `/etc/sysconfig/docker` (on the official *ECS community AMIs*), in the definition of `OPTIONS`:

```
OPTIONS="--ip-forward=true --iptables=true --bip="172.32.0.1/24" --storage-opt dm.basesize=100G"
```

So even if the host's **docker0** network interface is likely to have an IP address of *172.17.0.1*, it's better to retrieve it from the container by extracting the IP address of the gateway of the **docker0** network interface, this way:

`ip route|head -n 1|sed -r 's/default via ([0-9.]+).*$/\1/'`

---

So in my container, running these commands will return what I expect:

```
HOST_IP=$(ip route|head -n 1|sed -r 's/default via ([0-9.]+).*$/\1/')
clusterName=$(curl -s "http://$HOST_IP:51678/v1/metadata" | jq -r ".Cluster")
instanceArn=$(curl -s "http://$HOST_IP:51678/v1/metadata" | jq -r ".ContainerInstanceArn")
```